# editor option not available in dashboard

Tags: editor, wp-config

The editor option not showing up in the dashboard. I tried to set to `false` the statement

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
```

But there is not any statement like this in wp-config file. What to do?

Comment: Some plugins, themes, and even some hosts disable this because it's very risky to have it available. Have you tried disabling all plugins?

Comment: i disable all pulgins already but nothing changed ..!!

Comment: Are you hosting this somewhere or is this on your local environment?